# emular un contar.si de excel, con pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Tengo un reporte en mi trabajo, al cual le agrego una columna auxiliar(columna 'Aux'), que sirve de contador, a fin de individualizar unos códigos. A modo de ejemplo, dejo una muestra de lo que hago

```
Orden  aux  concat 
100    1    1001
100    2    1002
100    3    1003
101    1    1011
102    1    1021
102    2    1022
```

Lo que hace esa función en Excel, es ir contando los valores que se repiten, pero de forma escalada. Es decir, el primer "100" que aparece, en la columna 'Aux', figura un 1. si este "100" aparece otra vez, en la celda de al lado, figurara un 2, y así sucesivamente.

Ahora bien, en el proceso de automatizar este reporte, estoy buscando escribir la misma función en Python, y la verdad no me esta saliendo. Alguna idea?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
...

# Luego de leer el archivo csv etc, creas la columna llamada 'aux' con el index secuencial por cada grupo de los valores de 'orden'

df['aux'] = df.groupby('Orden').cumcount() + 1

# Luego concatenas el 'Orden' y 'aux' en la columna 'concat'
df['concat'] = df['Orden'].astype(str) + df['aux'].astype(str)
...
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias!